# Retrieving public posts from multiple Facebook pages at the same time using the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know this will let the user retrieve the latest 10 posts from cocacola page.

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/posts/access_token=[####]&limit=10

Is there any way I can retrieve the latest 10 posts from **cocacola and pepsi** Facebook pages at the same time.
Example:

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola&pepsi/posts/access_token=[####]&limit=10

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Sami

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the example you quoted, it's
`https://graph.facebook.com/posts?ids=cocacola,pepsi&access_token=[####]&limit=10`

In the general case `https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=<list of IDs>&fields=<list of fields`> will work.

This is covered briefly on the [main Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) under the heading 'selection'

Comment: Is there anyway I can merge posts from the two pages and order them by created_time?

Comment: array_merge followed by usort?