# facebook api undocumented posts endpoint

Tags: facebook

I am working on an old codebase which includes a few fb api calls.

One of them is hitting `/posts?ids=userId1,userId2...`
When searching through the facebook api reference this endpoint is nowhere seen though.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference

You can try it in the fb api explorer though, for example with:

`posts?ids= 89562268312`

So my question, is this still a valid endpoint and does documentation exist?

Update:

according to [Retrieving public posts from multiple Facebook pages at the same time using the Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845352/retrieving-public-posts-from-multiple-facebook-pages-at-the-same-time-using-the?rq=1) this was once documented under the point selection, but it seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering myself here in case someone stumbles over this, its not a direct endpoint, but as stated under

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#largerequests

> Multiple ID Read Requests
>
> You can make a single GET request that retrieves multiple nodes by using the ?ids endpoint with the object IDs of those nodes. For example, to lookup the Facebook Developers page and the current session user in a single request, you could use the following Graph API call:

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /photos?ids={user-id-a},{user-id-b}
```